# Symfony 4.4: How to create Keycloak authentication in functionnal tests?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, keycloak

I'm trying to upgrade a Symfony 4.3.6 application to v4.4.

The app uses [oauth2-client-bundle](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) to authenticate users with Keycloak. Consequently, users are never persisted in database.
Here is the security config:

```
security:
    providers:
        oauth:
            id: knpu.oauth2.user_provider
    firewalls:
        main:
            logout:
                path: app.logout
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\KeycloakAuthenticator
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/connect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        -
          path: ^/
          allow_if: "'127.0.0.1' == request.getClientIp() or is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
```

And here is the `KeycloakAuthenticator` service:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User; // extends KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\User\OAuthUser
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\Provider\KeycloakClient;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\SocialAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class KeycloakAuthenticator extends SocialAuthenticator
{
    private $clientRegistry;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->router         = $router;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'connect_keycloak_check' === $request->attributes->get('_route');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->fetchAccessToken($this->getKeycloakClient());
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $keycloakUser = $this->getKeycloakClient()->fetchUserFromToken($credentials);

        $user = new User($keycloakUser->getName(), ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', 'ROLE_USER']);
        $user->setEmail($keycloakUser->getEmail())
            ->setName($keycloakUser->getName())
            ->setLocale($keycloakUser->toArray()['locale'] ?? 'fr')
        ;

        return $user;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        // On success, let the request continue
        return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app.keycloak_start'), Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    }

    private function getKeycloakClient(): KeycloakClient
    {
        return $this->clientRegistry->getClient('keycloak');
    }
}
```

Functional tests are developped according to the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token):

```php
public function testHomePage()
{
        $client = static::createClient();
        $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewallName = 'main';
        $token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken(new User('foo', ['ROLE_USER']), $firewallName, $roles);

        $session->set('_security_'.$firewallName, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

        $client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
}
```

Until now, tests pass, everything is fine.

But since I upgraded Symfony to 4.4, the method `ControllerTrait::getUser()` returns `null` and I'm facing the following error when running functional tests:

> Error : Call to a member function getUsername() on null

I except to get the current user as usual when calling `$this->getUser()`.

I tried to manually set the token in the `security.token_storage` but the error still persists.
I also tried to force authentication by removing the part `"'127.0.0.1' == request.getClientIp()` in the `allow_if` section of "security.yaml", and the response is now a 307 Temporary Redirect to the Keycloak service.

Did the behavior of `$this->getUser()` change between this 2 versions ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you create a new User for `PostAuthenticationGuardToken` ? Because your provider will try to retrieve a user who does not exist

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. `PostAuthenticationGuardToken` takes a `UserInterface` as first parameter, I have to instanciate a new User in this context. How would do this?

Comment: Check it here https://github.com/EnMarche/en-marche.fr/blob/master/tests/Controller/ControllerTestTrait.php#L173 and also L69 or L78 ;)

Comment: In my case users are never persisted in the database thus, I have no repository to fetch user from it. That's why I create a new instance of `App\Entity\User`.
In you example, the `UserInterface` object is fetched from database, right?

Comment: yes you're right in my example user is fetched from database... could you add also `KeycloakAuthenticator` ?

Comment: Sure, I just did

Comment: Did you try to add `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` role to new User in your tests?

Comment: Yes I tried but I've got the same error `Call to a member function getUsername() on null`

Comment: I also tried to create a fresh project with Symfony 4.4 with the strict minimum and I'm facing the same issue. It looks like the behavior changed?